# Getting bad square-wave from the function generator

Tags: function-generator

I have a small function generator:
http://www.velleman.co.uk/contents/en-uk/p371_hpg1.html

And using the following device for DAQ:
http://www.mccdaq.com/PDFs/manuals/USB-1208LS.pdf

I hook up the generator output directly to the daq board. At 1Hz output I see he following plot(sampling rate is 500Hz):

[image]

It doesn't look like a nice square wave. When I increase the freq. it gets a little better.

What can be the problem?

[image]

Comment: Hah, you've got your 'scope set for AC coupling. (oops or AC coupling into the DAC perhaps)

Comment: how can I fix this since Im using a DAQ board not a scope? And why does it happen?

Comment: Are you AC coupling somewhere?  It's possible it is in the ground line.  Is the DAC single ended?

Comment: yes it is single ended. other channels are not plugged

Comment: Hmm those are pins 2 and 3 of your dac?  I'm sorry I don't know that DAC.  Do you have a scope?  maybe make your own ~square wave with a battery and switch and see that the DAC reads that correctly.  (Is the problem in the DAC or the sig gen or your connection?)

Comment: pins are correct you can see at page 23 in the manual i linked. daq measures well normally. function generator is very new. connections are as in the photo i used bnc as well. the same result. my scope is from 1970s analog and i can only see pulses more than some hundreds Hz, they look fine. but i cannot see 1Hzin scope.

Comment: just acts as a scope with ac coupling settings

Comment: This is perfectly normal for a 1 Hz signal with scope in AC coupled, try 100 Hz and see what you get.

Comment: yes but my problem is not the scope, the daq measures the square wave as if there is capacitance effect somewhere. the  setup photo is in my question.

Comment: maybe i need to dc couple my daq??

Comment: http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-4/input-and-output-coupling/ This link states that low freq. square waves can easily get ac coupled. can it be the reason????

Comment: I don't want you to blow up your DAC, but try hooking the sig gen ground to the DAC ground.  (maybe with ~1k R's in series to limit current?)

Comment: they re allready connected. its a single ended wiring.

Comment: My guess is the signal generator is AC coupled... And not designed to work at 1Hz

Comment: can we verify it from the schematics?: http://www.velleman.eu/images/tmp/HPG1%20technical%20doc%20V1.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the [schematic of the signal generator](http://www.velleman.eu/images/tmp/HPG1%20technical%20doc%20V1.pdf) (page 8) clearly shows that it is AC-coupled.

IC4 is the output attenuator, and IC3B is the output driver. C4, C20 and C21 are the coupling between them. In conjunction with R7, they give you a time constant of roughly 1 second, which explains the "droop" you see on a 1-Hz square wave.

EDIT: The issue here is that the DAC (IC2) is single-ended — it can only produce positive voltages. In order to get an output that swings both positive and negative, the AC coupling is used to remove the DC bias.

If your application does not require negative output voltages, you could simply short out the coupling capacitors by installing a temporary wire across one of them.

If you do still want bipolar output voltages, but a much lower cutoff frequency, Google for the phrase "dc offset servo circuit". The basic concept is that you use an active low-pass filter to isolate the DC component, and then subtract this from the original signal in the output stage.

The point is, that it's much easier (i.e., more compact) to create a low-pass filter with a low cutoff frequency than it is to create a high-pass filter with the same cutoff frequency. For example, a 1 MΩ resistor and a 100 µF capacitor will get you down to the milliHertz range.

Comment: why would they do that. so is this device useless for 1Hz???

Comment: It's probably primarily intended for audio testing, in which a high-pass cutoff frequency of 0.16 Hz is more than adequate.

Comment: is it possible to correct it for me?

Comment: See edit above.

Comment: they sell this device without mentioning you will never get a nice square wave for very low freq.